# Heroku app crashes on startup for seemingly no reason (when it was working before recent push)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

**Ruby Version:** 2.0

**Rails Version** 4.0

App works perfect on local environment, but since pushing recent changes to Heroku, I am getting this error page:

[image]

This is what I am seeing in the logs:

**From push:**

```
2013-08-22T00:57:54.227337+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy bc28117 by drew.j.wyatt@gmail.com
2013-08-22T00:57:54.255350+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v40 created by drew.j.wyatt@gmail.com
2013-08-22T00:57:54.419023+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-08-22T00:57:54+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2013-08-22T00:58:00.449104+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 29832 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-08-22T00:58:04.150485+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/debug_helper.rb:29:in `debug': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
2013-08-22T00:58:04.150485+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.0/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.150485+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.0/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:78:in `instance_eval'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.150485+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.0/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:78:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.150485+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `call'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.150485+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.150485+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.150485+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.150485+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.150485+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:62:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.150718+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.150718+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.150718+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.150718+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.150718+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.150718+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.150718+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.150718+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.150718+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.150718+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.150908+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.150908+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.150908+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.150908+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.150908+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `require'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.150908+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.150908+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.150908+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.150908+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.150908+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.151393+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.151393+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.151393+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.151393+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.151393+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.151393+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.151393+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.151393+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.151393+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.151393+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.151551+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.151551+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.151551+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2013-08-22T00:58:04.182727+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-08-22T00:58:04.182727+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.0.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:29832
2013-08-22T00:58:04.182727+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2013-08-22T00:58:04.182727+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-08-22T00:58:04.182727+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2013-08-22T00:58:05.602995+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-08-22T00:58:05.628596+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

**from rake db:migrate (immediately after)**

```
2013-08-22T00:58:16.075148+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by drew.j.wyatt@gmail.com
2013-08-22T00:58:27.526580+00:00 heroku[run.2964]: Awaiting client
2013-08-22T00:58:27.526580+00:00 heroku[run.2964]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-08-22T00:58:28.668358+00:00 heroku[run.2964]: State changed from starting to up
2013-08-22T00:58:31.632038+00:00 heroku[run.2964]: Process exited with status 1
2013-08-22T00:58:31.652631+00:00 heroku[run.2964]: State changed from up to complete
2013-08-22T00:59:15.725601+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-08-22T00:59:21.894733+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 31681 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-08-22T00:59:26.949871+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/debug_helper.rb:29:in `debug': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
2013-08-22T00:59:26.949871+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.0/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.949871+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.0/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:78:in `instance_eval'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.949871+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.0/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:78:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.949871+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `call'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.949871+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.949871+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.949871+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.949871+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.949871+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:62:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.950056+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.950056+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.950056+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.950056+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.950056+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.950056+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.950325+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.950325+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.950325+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.950325+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.950325+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.950325+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.950325+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.950325+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.950325+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `require'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.950325+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.950464+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.950464+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.950464+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.950464+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.950464+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.950464+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.950464+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.950464+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.950464+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.950464+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.950599+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.950599+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.950599+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.950599+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.950599+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.950599+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.950599+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2013-08-22T00:59:26.976757+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-08-22T00:59:26.976757+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.0.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:31681
2013-08-22T00:59:26.976757+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2013-08-22T00:59:26.976757+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-08-22T00:59:26.976757+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2013-08-22T00:59:28.249923+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-08-22T00:59:28.260791+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Here is the dump from the terminal running the push and migrate.

**the push**

```
Drews-MacBook-Pro:depot drewwyatt$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 11, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 524 bytes, done.
Total 6 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       Using rake (10.1.0)
       Using i18n (0.6.5)
       Using minitest (4.7.5)
       Using multi_json (1.7.9)
       Using atomic (1.1.12)
       Using thread_safe (0.1.2)
       Using tzinfo (0.3.37)
       Using activesupport (4.0.0)
       Using builder (3.1.4)
       Using erubis (2.7.0)
       Using rack (1.5.2)
       Using rack-test (0.6.2)
       Using actionpack (4.0.0)
       Using mime-types (1.23)
       Using polyglot (0.3.3)
       Using treetop (1.4.14)
       Using mail (2.5.4)
       Using actionmailer (4.0.0)
       Using activemodel (4.0.0)
       Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
       Using arel (4.0.0)
       Using activerecord (4.0.0)
       Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
       Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
       Using execjs (1.4.0)
       Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Using thor (0.18.1)
       Using railties (4.0.0)
       Using coffee-rails (4.0.0)
       Using hike (1.2.3)
       Using jbuilder (1.5.0)
       Using jquery-rails (3.0.4)
       Using jquery-ui-rails (4.0.4)
       Using json (1.8.0)
       Using pg (0.16.0)
       Using pony (1.5)
       Using bundler (1.3.2)
       Using tilt (1.4.1)
       Using sprockets (2.10.0)
       Using sprockets-rails (2.0.0)
       Using rails (4.0.0)
       Using rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.1)
       Using rails_stdout_logging (0.0.1)
       Using rails_12factor (0.0.2)
       Using rdoc (3.12.2)
       Using sass (3.2.10)
       Using sass-rails (4.0.0)
       Using sdoc (0.3.20)
       Using turbolinks (1.3.0)
       Using uglifier (2.1.2)
       Updating files in vendor/cache
       Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Detected manifest file, assuming assets were compiled locally
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types      -> (none)
       Default types for Ruby/Rails -> console, rake, web, worker

-----> Compiled slug size: 41.7MB
-----> Launching... done, v40
       http://mightywash-supply-store.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:mightywash-supply-store.git
   8fc845a..bc28117  master -> master
```

**the rake**

```
Drews-MacBook-Pro:depot drewwyatt$ heroku run rake db:migrate
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.2964
rake aborted!
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/debug_helper.rb:29:in `debug'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.0/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.0/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:78:in `instance_eval'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.0/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:78:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:62:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/app/config/environment.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:249:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

**Update 1**

Following Gene's advice, I ran `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` - and the rake failed on my local machine too. Results below:

```
Drews-MacBook-Pro:depot drewwyatt$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
rake aborted!
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
/Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/debug_helper.rb:29:in `debug'
/Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.0/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.0/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:78:in `instance_eval'
/Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.0/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:78:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `call'
/Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
/Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
/Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
/Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:62:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
/Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/Users/drewwyatt/Sites/Ruby/Rails/Tutorials/depot/config/environment.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
/Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
/Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
/Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:249:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: I'd look at line 25 in `environment.rb` first.  What is it?

Comment: @Gene
`Depot::Application.initialize!`

Comment: Okay.  Since it's dying in sprockets it's probably an assets problem.  If you are using precompiled assets, recompile them and push again.

Comment: @Gene Just by doing a `rake assets:precompile`?

Comment: In Rails 3.2 it's `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`.  I believe it hasn't changed for Rails 4, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Alternately you can just push after deleting precompiled assets with `bin/rake assets clean`.  I could have used `bin/rake` instead of `bundle exec rake` above, too.  Either should be good.  The build on Heroku will take longer because it's compiling assets with your dyno.

Comment: @Gene well, I think I may have found something new - it looks like things are breaking for production on my local machine too. I'll post the output in my question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36017/discussion-between-gene-and-anwyatt)