# Error depolying a rails app to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have got the following error deploying to Heroku. The app works fine on the local machine. The followings are the log message. I have also listed my gem file below. Please kindly guide me.

Thanks

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

    gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

    # Bundle edge Rails instead:
    # gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

    gem 'pg'

    #profiler
    gem 'rack-mini-profiler'

    # Gems used only for assets and not required
    # in production environments by default.
    group :assets do
      gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'

      # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
      gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
      gem 'less-rails'
      gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'

      gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
    end

    gem 'jquery-rails'
    gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

    gem 'will_paginate'

    gem 'simple_form'

    gem 'puppet'

    gem 'scaffold'

    # attachments
    gem 'paperclip', '~> 3.4.2'
    gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.11.0'

    # optional, for attaching images 
    gem 'rmagick', '~> 2.13.2'

    gem 'devise'
    gem 'cancan'
    gem 'rolify'

    gem 'bootstrap-sass'

    gem 'friendly_id'

    # To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
    # gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

    # To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
    # gem 'jbuilder'

    # Use unicorn as the app server
    # gem 'unicorn'

    # Deploy with Capistrano
    # gem 'capistrano'

    # To use debugger
    # gem 'debugger'
```

**Heroku Logs**

```
    Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 40708`
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.274806+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from  at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.274806+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from  at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.288405+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `block in ': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.288405+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/templater-1.0.0/lib/templater/core_ext/kernel.rb:7:in `instance_exec'
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.288405+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.288405+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.288405+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.288405+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.288405+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.288405+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.288405+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `'
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.288405+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.288619+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.288619+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.288619+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.288619+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in '
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.288619+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.288619+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.288619+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.288619+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `'
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.288619+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.288619+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.288619+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.288619+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.289021+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.289021+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.289021+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in '
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.289021+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.289021+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.289021+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `'
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.289021+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `'
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.289021+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.318516+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.318516+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.13 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:40708
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.318516+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.318516+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
    2013-08-25T01:48:46.318516+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
    2013-08-25T01:48:47.493705+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2013-08-25T01:48:47.509416+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2013-08-25T01:52:31.279456+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=staging-rms.herokuapp.com fwd="172.27.218.225, 137.132.3.10" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

`
```

Comment: Possible repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370140/heroku-app-crashes-on-startup-for-seemingly-no-reason-when-it-was-working-befor#comment26994093_18370140

Comment: Maybe something with the asset pipeline? I had to add this Gem to my Gemfile: gem "rails_12factor", but I used rails 4..

Comment: I added "rails_12factor" and tried. But didn't work as wel..

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem by removing 'puppet' and 'scaffold' gems from the Gemfile. :)